# SQL, Return Records for last batch run by As of Date

Tags: sql, subquery, maxdate

I have a table where the AsOfDate has multiple BatchDates:

```
>Cmmt || AsOfDate            || BatchDate
>
>6789 || 2016-02-11 00:00:00 || 2016-02-11 09:32:05
>
>6789 || 2016-02-11 00:00:00 || 2016-02-11 11:48:22
>
>2598 || 2016-02-12 00:00:00 || 2016-02-12 10:32:05
>
>6789 || 2016-02-12 00:00:00 || 2016-02-12 10:32:05
>
>6789 || 2016-02-12 00:00:00 || 2016-02-12 12:48:22
```

I want to return all records for the maximum batchdate-

The result should be:

```
>Cmmt || AsOfDate            || BatchDate
>
>2598 || 2016-02-12 00:00:00 || 2016-02-12 12:48:22
>
>6789 || 2016-02-12 00:00:00 || 2016-02-12 12:48:22
```

I've tried this but I keep returning all records and dates:

```
>SELECT w.AsOfDate
>      ,w.BatchDate
>      ,w.Balance
>
> FROM bi.RWAFinanceReport w
>
>>INNER JOIN (
        >>>SELECT AsOfDate, MAX(BatchDate) AS MaxBatchDate
>
        >>>FROM bi.RWAFinanceReport GROUP BY AsOfDate) x 
>
        >>>on w.AsofDate=x.AsOfDate AND w.BatchDate=x.MaxBatchDate
>
>WHERE w.Balance<>0
```

Anyone have some tips on how to resolve this?

/************/

### Solved this beast today.

There's two subselect queries here, one to find the maxbatchdate- The next one I want is to find the max date. Formulating these questions is hard...

```
>  INNER JOIN (
>             SELECT ProductID, AsOfDate, MAX(BatchDate) AS MaxBatchDate
>             FROM bi.RWAFinanceReport GROUP BY ProductID, AsOfDate) x 
>             on w.ProductID=x.ProductID AND w.AsOfDate=x.AsOfDate _
>               AND w.BatchDate=x.MaxBatchDate
>
> INNER JOIN (
>                    SELECT MAX(AsOfDate) AS MaxAsOfDate
>                    FROM bi.RWAFinanceReport) y 
>                    on w.AsOfDate = y.MaxAsOfDate
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in the results, BatchDate for 2598 should be "2016-02-12 10:32:05"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you shouldn't be grouping by `AsOfDate`, but rather by `Cmmt`.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT w.AsOfDate
      ,w.BatchDate
      ,w.Balance
FROM bi.RWAFinanceReport w
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Cmmt, MAX(BatchDate) AS MaxBatchDate
        FROM bi.RWAFinanceReport 
        GROUP BY Cmmt) x 
    on w.Cmmt=x.Cmmt AND w.BatchDate=x.MaxBatchDate
WHERE w.Balance<>0
```

Comment: When I replace AsOfDate with Cmmt I still get every single AsOfDate and BatchDate :-/ perhaps the Inner Join is the issue?

Comment: I tried with the sample data you have above, and this query worked for me.  Returned 2 rows, one for each unique cmmt.